# Populate document name and title from uploaded file

Tags: kentico

When adding a new file (cms.file) manually in the content tree I would like to be able to populate the document name and title using the name of the uploaded file. Is this possible ? If so can anyone point me in the right direction in terms of how to implement. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach to eg. `DocumentEvents.Insert.Before` event and check if page type is `cms.file` and perform custom actions. You can learn more about handling global events [here](https://docs.kentico.com/k8/custom-development/handling-global-events).

Your code could look something like:

```
using System; 

using CMS.Base; 
using CMS.DocumentEngine; 

[ChangeFileNameAttibute] 
public partial class CMSModuleLoader 
{ 
private class ChangeFileNameAttibute : CMSLoaderAttribute 
{ 
    public override void Init() 
    { 
        DocumentEvents.Insert.Before += Insert_Before; 
    } 

    void Insert_Before(object sender, DocumentEventArgs e) 
    { 
        if (e.Node.ClassName.ToLower() == "cms.file") 
        { 
            e.Node.doSomething(); // You can edit document here
        } 
    } 
} 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it looks like these events happen too late. Just to be clear I'm looking to access the event (if there is one) triggered by the uploading of the file (before the document is saved)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by cloning the page used to create a new file located here `/CMSModules/Content/CMSDesk/New/NewFile.aspx` in your Kentico instance.  Best practice state to clone it to your own directory and make the changes needed.

What I've done in the past is modified the `ProcessFileUploader()` and `ProcessDirectUploader()` methods to extract the value setting into a single function.  Then updated those methods above to use the newly called method setting those important values.

New function:

```
private void SetFileFieldValues(ref TreeNode node, string fileName)
{
    int maxFileNameLength = FileNameFieldInfo.Size;
    if (fileName.Length > maxFileNameLength)
    {
        fileName = fileName.Substring(0, maxFileNameLength);
    }

    node.DocumentName = fileName;

    if (node.ContainsColumn("FileName"))
    {
        node.SetValue("FileName", fileName);
    }

    if (node.ContainsColumn("FileLongName"))
    {
        string fileLongName = txtFileLongName.Text.Trim();
        fileLongName = TextHelper.LimitLength(fileLongName, txtFileLongName.MaxLength);
        node.SetValue("FileLongName", fileLongName);
    }

    if (node.ContainsColumn("FileShortName"))
    {
        string fileShortName = txtFileShortName.Text.Trim();
        fileShortName = TextHelper.LimitLength(fileShortName, txtFileShortName.MaxLength);
        node.SetValue("FileShortName", fileShortName);
    }

    if (node.ContainsColumn("FileDescription"))
    {
        string fileDescription = txtFileDescription.Text.Trim();
        fileDescription = TextHelper.LimitLength(fileDescription, txtFileDescription.MaxLength);

        node.SetValue("FileDescription", fileDescription);
    }

    if(node.ContainsColumn("DocumentSearchExcluded"))
    {
        bool excludeFromSearch = ValidationHelper.GetBoolean(cbxExcludeFromSearch.Checked, false);
        node.SetValue("DocumentSearchExcluded", excludeFromSearch);
    }
}
```

Updated methods:

```
protected void ProcessFileUploader()
{
    TreeNode node = DocumentManager.Node;

    // Create new document
    string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileUpload.FileName);

    SetFileFieldValues(ref node, fileName);

    node.SetValue("FileAttachment", Guid.Empty);

    // Set default template ID
    node.SetDefaultPageTemplateID(DataClass.ClassDefaultPageTemplateID);

    // Ensures documents consistency (blog post hierarchy etc.)
    DocumentManager.EnsureDocumentsConsistency();

    // Insert the document
    DocumentHelper.InsertDocument(node, DocumentManager.ParentNode, DocumentManager.Tree);

    // Add the file
    DocumentHelper.AddAttachment(node, "FileAttachment", FileUpload.PostedFile, DocumentManager.Tree, ResizeToWidth, ResizeToHeight, ResizeToMaxSideSize);
}
```

And the other one

```
protected void ProcessDirectUploader()
{
    TreeNode node = DocumentManager.Node;

    // Create new document
    string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ucDirectUploader.AttachmentName);

    SetFileFieldValues(ref node, fileName);

    node.SetValue("FileAttachment", Guid.Empty);

    // Set default template ID
    node.SetDefaultPageTemplateID(DataClass.ClassDefaultPageTemplateID);

    // Ensures documents consistency (blog post hierarchy etc.)
    DocumentManager.EnsureDocumentsConsistency();

    // Insert the document
    DocumentHelper.InsertDocument(node, DocumentManager.ParentNode, DocumentManager.Tree);

    // Set the attachment GUID later - important when document is under workflow and  using check-in/check-out
    node.SetValue("FileAttachment", ucDirectUploader.Value);
}
```

Then last but not least, you need to update the File page type (or create a clone of your own) and add the file location for the New page in the page type definition.

It may not be exactly what you need but should get you very close to what you need to do.